# python 3, Recursion, Or in return statement

Tags: python, recursion

I have a code that checks if a given list of integers can sum up to a specified target. If any combination of the integers in a list can sum up to a target value, it returns True. The input 'start' is the index of the list that I want to start from and continue until the end of the list

```
def groupSum(start, nums, target):
    if start >= len(nums):
        return target == 0
    else:
        return groupSum(start + 1, nums, target - nums[start]) or groupSum(start + 1, nums, target);
```

So, if I put

```
groupSum(0, [2,4,8], 10)
```

it will return True, and, if I put

```
groupSum(0, [2,4,8], 9)
```

it will return False

QUESTION: I don't understand how they can put 'or' in the return statements, in a recursive case. I don't see how that's actually working. Is it passing multiple functions simultaneously to check every combination or what?

I'm pretty new to Recursion method and would appreciate it if you can explain the technique used here. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In python `and` and `or` operators, **do not** return boolean values. They return the last thing evaluated. So, when you

```
return a or b
```

if `a` is a truthy value, `a` will be returned. Otherwise, the truthness of the expression depends on `b`, and so `b` will be returned.

Comment: I still don't understand how it works in my case. How do I know my recursive function with which input will be returned? I don't see how this works, specifically in a recursive case

Comment: You don't know *which one* will be returned. The first one will be called. If its return value is *truthy*, this value will be returned. Otherwise, the output of the second term will be returned, no matter what that output is

Answer (score 0):

Why it's `True` for 10 is because there's an exact match for 10 (8+2); which your recursive function reduces to 0 for the target variable.

So, `groupSum(start + 1, nums, target - nums[start])` this becomes `True` - so the comparison will be True or False, which will turn out to True!

Now, for the value of 9, there's no such match and hence it'll always remain `False`.

You can try for 12 and 6 as well. It'll return True.

Whereas, for any other value the comparison will always be False or False.